# Calling Javascript

Tags: cross-domain, httprequest

I want to call a webservice using http post/get in my html webpage using javascript.

Link is shown below,
http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx/GetCitiesByCountry?CountryName=Nepal

It is a cross domian call and i want to call it directly on my webpage,

I want to access the data of this link using javascript.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't control that domain, and I'm guessing you don't. You will need to create a web application that can act as a proxy and call this xml code server side. (As there are no cross domain restrictions)

You can then call your own web application via an AJAX request on the frontend.

Comment: hi, can u give me some sample application.??

Comment: You will need to write your own web applciation to handle this Im afraid. This could be done quickly using a web framework (such as CakePHP) if you are familiar with any

Comment: hi cowls,
i am not familier with the PHP framwork. Is there no other way out to have this xml data standalone.???

Comment: What are you running your website on currently?

Comment: hi,
i havnt created any web application its just a basic html page which i am running using localhost by moongose(i am not very much familier with mongoos tough). There is no server for this.